# Is this a normal load for Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

Load average: 0.05 0.13 0.15
Uptime: 28 days

Not sure what those mean or if there is a script that will help me figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

Quote:
In short it is the average sum of the number of processes waiting in the run-queue plus the number currently executing over 1, 5, and 15 minute time periods

So the number of actual running processes -- plus the number of "ready to run" processes i.e. active programs which are not waiting for IO or timers or are otherwise blocked.

So you have a four processor machine and you load average is 3.5 then nothing is waiting. On the other hand if the load average was 5.2 there would be one process waiting for resources at any given time. If you get up to 8 or 9 on the third number (15 minute average) then you have  a problem!

Answer (score 0):

That looks pretty low to me (that's good).  Here's what Wikipedia has to say:

"For single-CPU systems that are CPU-bound, one can think of load average as a percentage of system utilization during the respective time period. For systems with multiple CPUs, one must divide the number by the number of processors in order to get a comparable percentage."

So, if you have a single-core system, thats 5% (last minute) 13% (5 minute) and 15% (15 minute).

(from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_(computing))